# HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request while searching in elastic search using spring restemplate

Tags: java, android, spring, elasticsearch, spring-rest

I have seen many question to this but nothing solved my issue. I am using elasticsearch search query json to search my data using spring resttemplate. Please help.

I am doing this in asyntask android

```
@Override
protected List<JobPosts> doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    List list = null;

    try {

        SearchForm searchForms = (SearchForm) objects[0];

        String searchJson="";




        String plainCreds = "*********:********";



        final String url = "********";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(searchJson, headers);
        Log.d("location", "before exchange");
        ResponseEntity<JobPosts[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, JobPosts[].class);
        JobPosts[] jobPosts = response.getBody();

        Log.d("location", "after exchange");
        list = Arrays.asList(jobPosts);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("location", e.getMessage());
    }
```

and i get this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
  at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:76)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:524)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:481)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)
  at in.thoughtsmith.jink.MapsActivity$SearchJob.doInBackground(MapsActivity.java:689)
  at in.thoughtsmith.jink.MapsActivity$SearchJob.doInBackground(MapsActivity.java:647)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1115) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:590) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: What exception do you see in your ES server logs? Also I don't think your `searchJson` string is correct.

Comment: i used same searchJson String in sense extension and it give me valid result.. also i didn't got you what does ES server logs means. Sorry i am new to this

Comment: The query is probably ok, but you cannot paste it like that in Java code, you need to make a real string out of it. I'm even surprised that your code compiles

Comment: Also you should not post the same questions several times, I've already closed your previous one because it was the exact same as an earlier one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240927/how-to-search-via-json-in-elastic-search-using-spring-resttemplate-in-android which already has an answer.

Comment: Sorry it is dyncamic string which is created at run time when user enters skills and i didnt wanted to post that code .... i will edit my question

Comment: i made correction

Answer (score 0):

Your query searchJson is not valid JSON. I surrounded it with {}:

```
String searchJson="{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"mandatorySkills.skillName\":\"j2ee\"}}],\"filter\":[{\"geo_distance\":{\"distance\":\"50km\",\"location\":{\"lat\":19.1237818,\"lon\":72.8907772}}},{\"range\":{\"minimumExperience\":{\"lte\":6}}},{\"range\":{\"maximumExperience\":{\"gte\":6}}}]}}}";
```

Comment: i did this ... getting same exception again

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue. The exception message was not very helpful. I have to do a
`e.getResponseBodyAsString()` where `e` is the exception. I found the detailed error message. You will see error like:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"VALIDATION_FAILURE","source":{"pointer":"employee/attributes/child[0].role"},"detail":"... is invalid"}]}
```